# Show text if attribute is set as Yes - Magento 1

Tags: javascript, php, algolia

I have a variable that is Yes/no

Need to hide the price and show a custom text if this variable is set to Yes, how we can achive this quick and easy

Answer (score 0):

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Set "Used in Product View page" to Yes

Then in view.phtml :

```
if($_product->getAttributeText('name_price')=='yes')
{
    echo "display text";
}
```

Comment: How do you know also the name of the variable if he didn't specify anything? ahah

Comment: name doesn't matter, I just used a random name dear.

Comment: The variable name is just a nitpick, it seems that you know everything from your comment. Idk Rick, it seems a fake

Comment: hahah. if you think it's a fake then stay happy on your judgements bud.

Comment: Thanks but, In my case this solution not work because this template  using a mustache code.

Answer (score 0):

1)You should specify more than that. Do you want to do that in javascript or php? 2)If a value can assume 2 values, I think is better use boolean.
3)If the condition is true (the variable is yes), do you want to change a value in an object or what? 
So I'm going to write pseudo code for you...

```
if (myVariable) then
    object = {
        ....
        visibility: false
    }
else 
    {...}

if(object.visibility) then
    customText = "Custom Text"
```

Comment: I have a attribute snap_ship. I like to show some text if attribute is selected as yes. I try  In hit-item.phtml - This is template from algolia search.  

{{#snap_ship}} some text {{/snap_ship}} 
{{^snap_ship}}  no text {{/snap_ship}}

I think it should be defined as boolean record with true and false, because this template using mustache.  But I do not know how to define it.